# Are there Dedekind-infinite amorphous sets?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, constructive-mathematics

An *amorphous set* is an infinite set (i.e. cannot be put into bijection with any finite set $\{ 1, \dots, n \}$ for any $n$) that cannot be partitioned into two mutually disjoint infinite subsets. Amorphous sets are typically presented as examples of infinite sets that are not Dedekind-infinite (i.e. sets $A$ which have injective functions $f : A \rightarrow A$ that are not bijective), i.e. are Dedekind-finite, although they are not the only known class of examples. I reproduce the proof-sketch typically given for context.

Indeed, assume that $A$ is Dedekind-infinite, and so has an injective function $f$ as above. Define the sets $A_n$ for elements $x \in A$ that are in the image of the $n$-fold composition of $f$ with itself, but not in the image of the $(n+1)$-fold image of $f$. (In particular, $A_0$ would then be the set of elements outside the image of $f$; that is, $A_0 = A \setminus \mathop{\rm Im} f$.) Then, these sets are clearly mutually disjoint, and (and keep this point in the argument in mind for later) all of them are nonempty. Now, the two sets $X = \bigcup_{k = 0}^\infty A_{2k}$ and $Y = \bigcup_{k = 0}^\infty A_{2k + 1}$ give a partitioning of (some subset of) $A$, and so $A$ cannot be amorphous.

This proof is cited in a bunch of places, in particular in the Wikipedia article on the subject ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set)). However, I had recently become interested in properties of amorphous sets in a constructive setting, in which case the given proof for this claim (seemingly) **fails**. The culprit is that showing each set $A_n$ is inhabited critically relies on the law of excluded middle. To summarize, one can indeed construct each set $A_{n + 1}$ from $A_n$ by taking its image under $f$, but to establish the base case, i.e. that $A_0$ itself is inhabited, one has to produce an element of the complement of the image of $f$, which relies on LEM.

This suggests to me two paths forward; either,

1. there exists some constructive proof of each $A_n$ being inhabited that I have missed, and therefore the theorem is also constructively valid; or
2. it is possible, constructively, for Dedekind-infinite amorphous sets to exist.

A potential path to exhibiting Dedekind-infinite amorphous set is to construct an injective function $f : A \rightarrow A$ that is bijective if LEM holds, but is (generally) not otherwise. One way one might do this is to consider some subset that cannot be shown to equal to $A$ without LEM (or at least, decidable equality for $A$) such as $S_a := \{ x \in A \mid x = a \vee x \neq a \}$ for some fixed element $a \in A$. Such a subset has the property that no explicit element of its complement can be constructed, but nonetheless it cannot be shown to be empty either. However, constructing any injective function $\varphi_a : X \rightarrow S_a$ alludes me, and so here is where I come to the Internet for possibly more information or guidance, possibly even an answer.

Thus, to summarize my question(s), here they are:

- **Can there be Dedekind-infinite amorphous if the assumption of the law of excluded middle is dropped? If there is, are there any models that contain them? Can the injective function $\varphi_a$ above be constructed constructively?**

---

Edit: fixed minor grammatical error.

Comment: If I understand the definition correctly, $\mathbb R$ is amorphous under the assumption that all functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are continuous, and it is clearly Dedekind infinite.

Comment: Does it help to use a simpler version of your even/odd argument? Namely, start with a single element $a_0$ not in the range of $f$ and apply $f$ successively. This gives a subset bijective with $\mathbb{N}$, and this clearly is not amorphous, since you can look at the even and odd elements. I'm not sure whether this avoids the issues of LEM or not, but it seems a little more concrete than the argument you described.

Comment: Ah, I see that you mention the LEM issue arises in the difficulty of finding an element not in the range of $f$, even though we have assumed $f$ is injective but not bijective. (I fear I shall never fully grok non-classical logic mathematics.)

Comment: Dear @JoelDavidHamkins, non-classical logic mathematics is just one further part of the multiverse :-) With the interesting phenomenon that forcing no longer needs to preserve and reflect the truth of bounded first-order statements, if the base universe is nonclassical.

Comment: I suppose that the bigger issue is how to define Dedekind-infinite in the absence of LEM. We already have a dozen definitions in ZF (and half of which are "not Dedekind-finite" for various equivalent definitions of DF). Which one is "the right one" when LEM is, um, excluded.

Comment: Dirk van Dalen's ["How Connected is the Intuitionistic Continuum?" (1997)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2275631) may give pointers.